# angular 2 data binding template for @input

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm curious to know how you guys would convert binding a data input from

```
template: `<guage-bar [guage]=guageBar></guage-bar>`
```

to doing something like this

```
let data = new PercentValue(20, 100); 
let guageBar = new GuageBar(this.data,'Database Health');

GuageBarComponent.guage = this.guageBar;
```

I've tried this and it doesn't work. My end goal is trying to do input property values inside another class using a service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html) and use the lifecycle hook [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewInit-class.html) to set the value

```
import { ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  template: `<guage-bar></guage-bar>`
})
class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(GuageBarComponent) guageBarCmp: GuageBarComponent;

  // the child component is available when this is called.
  // before that it will be null
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    guageBarCmp.guageBar = guageBar;
  }
}
```